# how to make wildfly 10 use jsf jars from web-inf lib folder and not from default implementation that comes with it

Tags: jsf, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am creating a hellow world jsf application using Wildfly 10, Wildfly is using its own jsf implementation instead of the jsf implementation jars that i have provided in the WEB-INF --> lib folder. how to tell wildfly to use my jars from lib folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override server jar with ones from WEB-INF/lib or use them instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517000/how-to-override-server-jar-with-ones-from-web-inf-lib-or-use-them-instead)

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=wildfly+use+provided+jsf+libs+from+WEB-INF gave me the answer